# Tonal equalization on different images

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I am looking for an application doing motion detection. Basically, I take a picture referencing the background of the scene I am watching, and I am comparing it to the frame a get from the camera.

I use this [website](http://cvg.deis.unibo.it/motion_en.html) to implement my app. The frames are highly disturbed by luminosity and so on... According to it, I can improve the result of the differential computation using tonal equalization techniques. Search for "tonal registration" in the page for more information.

I am working with HSV images.

Based on my research, I could find *histogram equalization* but appears to not yield good performances. I though about to use *HDR* but I don't know if it will be really relevant due to the fact I am working in a real-time video surveillance system (no time to "waste", cannot afford to get frame a different exposure).

Which technique could allow me to make the photometric range of my images as close as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I participated in the development of surveillance system and there was a similar problem too. Instead of histogram equalization it used a different approach. Algorithm was as following:

```
For every pixel:
- Calculate an average luminosity around the pixel with some window (e.g. at square with 50 pixels)
- Calculate multiplier as some fixed value (like 128 for byte sized components)
divided by the average from previous step. Account for possible 
division by zero here. So Multiplier = 128 / (Average + small value)
- Multiply pixel luminosity by multiplier.
```

Averages can be calculated incrementally in one go for the whole frame and in real time. It allowed to remove luminosity variations  from clouds, changing weather etc. rather effectively.